# Dropzone with durandal and webapi Authorization issue

Tags: asp.net-web-api, durandal, dropzone.js

I'm using Drozonejs control with durandal, when I'm trying to upload any file in IE I got  401 unauthorized error in the web api service , it's working fine in chrome and I'm using windows authentication

her's my code in the attached event

```
  function attached(view) {
       var myDropzone6 = new Dropzone("#testZone",
             {

                 url: //link to url ,
                 autoProcessQueue: true,
                 maxFilesize: 3
             });

    }
```

and below is the html

```
<section>

    <form enctype="multipart/form-data">
        test zone
        <div class="dropzone" id="testZone">

        </div>
        zone 1

    </form>

</section>
```

Comment: What version of IE are you using?

Comment: Can you post your Web API code.